# sql null in c# and null coalescing operator

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i have the following sql command

```
var Query = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [file] FROM [ApplicationSettings] WHERE [id] = @id And username=@username", con);
Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", fileName);
Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName ?? //then what?! );
```

the userName is a string (NVARCHAR in the sql), sometimes it has a value and sometimes its set to null, 
so i have 2 cases

```
username='someUserName'
username=Null
```

how can i achieve this in the current syntax without if statements or any additional checking

Comment: you can try something like IsDBNull(userName)?UserName:"" while adding the parameter. not sure with syntax. but its a try

Comment: If you want to know how to set a parameter to null: `command.Parameters.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parameterValue ?? DBNull.Value;`

Comment: @adrianm please try it and you will find out why it wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT [file] FROM [ApplicationSettings] 
WHERE [id] = @id And username=ISNULL(@username,username)
```

If @username is NULL, it'll compare username to username which always will be true; and if it is not null, it'll then compare username = @username.
You could also use a CASE for comparison, but I find the above syntax more clean myself.